# CPPCheck: Ignore dirs and all sub dirs from analyses?

Tags: devops, cppcheck

I have read the manual at https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf and have found that I can use `-i` to ignore a directory. However, in my testing it doesn't seem to ignore the whole subdir. Example, I have a library that has a very long directory path (this is simplified) but I want to ignore everything under the top level

```
Root
> Lib
>> Lib dir 1
>>> file.c
>> Lib dir 2
>>> file.c
```

The wording

> To ignore certain folders you can use -i. This will skip analysis of source files in
> the foo folder.
> cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json -ifoo

Suggests that it will skip any files in the specified dir, not any subdirs.

Is there a way to skip the dir and all sub dirs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I had to achieve this was generating a `compile_commands.json` from cmake then write a python script to exclude anything that matched the filter I wanted to exclude, eg `/libA/` will exclude anything under libA